# regex in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

i want my textbox to accept just english and arabic charachters and i used [a-z\u0600-\u06ff] regex but it dosent work for arabic letters

Answer (score 0):

```
  ^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s@,=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF]|(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])){0,30}$
```

Expanded

```
^     
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9\s@,=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF] 
   |  
      (?:
           \uD802 [\uDE60-\uDE9F] 
        |  \uD83B [\uDE00-\uDEFF] 
      )
 ){0,30}
 $
```

[Try this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pydbqxgb/)